# OctoberCMS Frontend file upload not adding file but adding database entry

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have edited the Rainlab User plugin to allow for the user to upload a file on the frontend attached to their user profile. Works in the backend but not working on the frontend.

**Inside User.php Model**

```
    public $attachOne = [
    'avatar' => 'System\Models\File',
    'id_document' => 'System\Models\File' 
];

/**
 * @var array The attributes that are mass assignable.
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'surname',
    'login',
    'username',
    'email',
    'password',
    'password_confirmation',
    'created_ip_address',
    'last_ip_address',
    'id_document'
];
```

**Inside Account.php Component**

```
public function onSubmit()
    {
        if (!$user = $this->user()) {
            return;
        }

        $data = post();

        if ($this->updateRequiresPassword()) {
            if (!$user->checkHashValue('password', $data['password_current'])) {
                throw new ValidationException(['password_current' => Lang::get('rainlab.user::lang.account.invalid_current_pass')]);
            }
        }

        if (Input::hasFile('avatar')) {
            $user->avatar = Input::file('avatar');

        }

        if (Input::hasFile('id_document')) {
            $user->id_document = Input::file('id_document');
        }

        $user->fill($data);
        $user->save();

        /*
         * Password has changed, reauthenticate the user
         */
        if (array_key_exists('password', $data) && strlen($data['password'])) {
            Auth::login($user->reload(), true);
        }

        Flash::success(post('flash', Lang::get(/*Settings successfully saved!*/'rainlab.user::lang.account.success_saved')));

        /*
         * Redirect
         */
        if ($redirect = $this->makeRedirection()) {
            return $redirect;
        }

        $this->prepareVars();
    }
```

Inside update.htm component

```
<form data-request="onSubmit" data-request-files data-request-flash>

  <input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onSubmit">

  {{ form_token() }}
  {{ form_sessionKey() }}

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="accountName">Full Name</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="accountName" value="{{ user.name }}">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="accountEmail">Email</label>
      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="accountEmail" value="{{ user.email }}">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="accountEmail">ID Document</label>
      <input type="file" name="id_document">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="accountEmail">Avatar</label>
      <input type="file" name="avatar">
  </div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>

</form>
```

Result in system_files table when I submit the form

[Database return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8nYa.png)

How do I make sure it adds all needed details in order to upload the file. Even the storage does not reflect the file on upload.

Comment: I feel this is wrong here, `Inside Account.php Component`

Comment: hmm, seems all ok to me can you move `$user->fill($data);` before the file assignments, may be that can cause an issue ... may be

Comment: @bhucho I tried changing documents, didn't work.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya also tried moving this up before the assignment but that didn't work either :( Will try some other things and see if anything comes up.

Comment: does `Input::hasFile()` returns true for both your file uploads, you can do `dd(Input::hasFile());`